# Set up email in Windows 8 Mail without a Microsoft Account/Email Address?

Tags: windows, windows-8, email, user-accounts, windows-store-app

Is there a way to use the default Mail app in Windows 8 without signing in using a Microsoft Account?

I'd like to only add an Exchange account and have no need for an extra Microsoft Account on my computers/devices.

Comment: There are free and paid email applications on the Windows Store that do not have this requirement.  The default Mail application has certain requirements though.

Comment: Yeah, like not even having POP3 support, as if no-one uses it anymore. :/ There are workarounds, but that's of course not as optimal as having direct in-built support. Switch to a better mail app if you want advanced features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the normal Mail app requires a MS account/Live ID.